# How to add a 'delete all button' in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new with javascript and i try to make a to do list for the first time. I'm trying to add a button to delete all of the tasks in a to do list. I can't find how it works.

```
var inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");
inputField.focus(); 
inputField.onkeyup = function (event) {

  if (event.which === 13) { 
    var taak = inputField.value;

    if (inputField.value.length === 0 || inputField.value == " ") {
      return false;
    }

    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"), taak); 

    inputField.focus();
    inputField.select();
  }
};


function addNewItem(list, taak) {
  var date = new Date();
  var id = " " + date.getHours() + date.getMinutes() + date.getSeconds() + date.getMilliseconds();

  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.id = "taakItem" + id;

  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox"; 
  checkBox.id = "checkbox" + id; 
  checkBox.addEventListener("click", updateItemStatus);

  var gebeurtenis = document.createElement("gebeurtenis");
  gebeurtenis.id = "item" + id; // item + tijd
  gebeurtenis.innerText = taak;
  gebeurtenis.addEventListener("dblclick", deleteItem); 

  listItem.appendChild(checkBox); 
  listItem.appendChild(gebeurtenis); 

  list.appendChild(listItem); 

}  

function updateItemStatus() {
  var checkboxId = this.id.replace("checkbox", "");
  var taak = document.getElementById("item" + checkboxId);

  if (this.checked) {
    taak.className = "checked"; // Geeft classnaam checked voor de     opmaak
  } else {
    taak.className = ""; // Als hij niet aangevinkt is, gebeurt er     niets
  }
}


function deleteItem() {
  var gebeurtenisId = this.id.replace("item", "");
  document.getElementById("taakItem" + gebeurtenisId).style.display =     "none";
}

var deleteAll = document.getElementById("deleteAll");
```

i prefer to do it with an array and a loop but i don't know how. please help.

Comment: Incidentally, spaces are not allowed in HTML IDs.

Comment: Yes: `var id = " " + ...`.

Comment: Please don't destroy your post

Comment: The purpose of this site is not to help **YOU** but to help future users who might have the same question as you as well

Comment: Again stop destroying your post, the code you modified has no sense with the answers below now, I rolled it back (again)

Comment: @sem s: The way you avoid plagiarism is by *not plagiarizing.*  If you don't want the public to see your code (or whoever's code it is), then *don't post it on a public site.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <script>
  function deleteAll(){
        document.getElementById("todoList").innerHTML = '';
    }
 </script>

 <button onclick="deleteAll()">Delete All</button>
```

Update

```
<script>   
      function deleteAll(){
           var todo =  document.getElementById("todoList");
           var lis = todo.getElementsByTagName("li");
           console.log(lis);
           while(lis.length > 0){                   
              todo.removeChild(lis[0]);
           }
        };       

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your actual HTML it looks like when you add an event to your to-do list you're creating an `<li>` to a list. To delete all of these, you could simply delete all the `<li>`s within the list. If you're using JQuery it can be done with something like

```
    $(list).empty();
```

In regular JavaScript (with a for loop) it will be something like (borrowing some of

```
    var ulList = getElementById(list);
    var childs = ul.children();        
    for (var i = 1; i < ulList.childNodes.length - 1; i++) {
        list.removeChild(list.childNodes[i]);   
    }
```

Instead of the original

```
   getElementById(list).innerHTML = '';
```

List would be the ID of the list you're passing into your function.